# Wrong 2nd argument type in FragmentTransaction.replace()

Tags: android, android-fragments, replace, transactions

I am a beginner in android studio. I have read most of the errors with the 2nd argument type in `FragmentTransaction.replace(int, Fragment)` statement provided in the site. But none matched with the problem I face. I was trying to make a code where when somebody clicked the credit_button in the code, the credit_fragment would open.

**When I try to run the code I get the following error**
[image]

> 'replace(int, android.app.Fragment)' in 'android.app.FragmentTransaction' cannot be applied to '(int, com.example.rohit.test2.creditfragment)

**The part of the code in MainActivity.java where the fragment is being called is**
[image]

These are my import statements:

```
import android.app.Fragment;    
import android.app.Activity;        
import android.app.FragmentManager;     
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;  
import android.os.Bundle;  
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;   
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;           
import android.view.View;    
import android.content.Intent;   
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;   
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;   
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;      
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;   
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;      
import android.view.Menu;  
import android.view.MenuItem;
```

the `import android.app.Fragment` is shown as unused import statement

Comment: When you want to show code its better to copy paste that showing a picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your creditfragment extends Fragment? Also there are android.app.Fragment and android.support.v4.app.Fragment, the way your code is implemented your creditfragment should extend android.app.Fragment, make sure you're importing that one on creditfragment class.